# postgresql - getting multiple rows from two matching columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, inner-join

I have a table: **appointments**

[image of appointments table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VudEf.jpg)

Here, values in **parent_appointment_id** are the values of **appointment_id**.

Currently, I'm getting output like this:

`select appointment_id, date_time, parent_appointment_id from appointments where appointment_status = 'completed' and patient_id = 2`

```
  {
    "appointment_id": 44,
    "date_time": "2021-01-16T10:05:38.000Z",
    "parent_appointment_id": 44
  },
  {
    "appointment_id": 21,
    "date_time": "2020-08-14T11:20:00.000Z",
    "parent_appointment_id": 2
  },
  {
    "appointment_id": 22,
    "date_time": "2020-04-18T12:00:00.000Z",
    "parent_appointment_id": 2
  },
  {
    "appointment_id": 2,
    "date_time": "2019-03-17T11:30:00.000Z",
    "parent_appointment_id": 2
  }
]
```

**But I want to display *date_time* of parent_appointment_id too**

Like This:

```
  {
    "appointment_id": 44,
    "date_time": "2021-01-16T10:05:38.000Z",
    "parent_appointment_id": 44,
        {
          "date_time_of_parent": "2021-01-16T10:05:38.000Z"
        }
  },
  {
    "appointment_id": 21,
    "date_time": "2020-08-14T11:20:00.000Z",
    "parent_appointment_id": 2,
        {
          "date_time_of_parent": "2019-03-17T11:30:00.000Z"
        }
  },
  {
    "appointment_id": 22,
    "date_time": "2020-04-18T12:00:00.000Z",
    "parent_appointment_id": 2,
        {
          "date_time_of_parent": "2019-03-17T11:30:00.000Z"
        }
  },
  {
    "appointment_id": 2,
    "date_time": "2019-03-17T11:30:00.000Z",
    "parent_appointment_id": 2,
        {
          "date_time_of_parent": "2019-03-17T11:30:00.000Z"
        }
  }
]
```

**Can you please guide me to write postgresql query to get this output.**

Comment: So you want to `JOIN` the table to itself as described in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self-join:

```
select a.appointment_id, a.date_time, a.parent_appointment_id, 
    p.date_time as date_time_of_parent
from appointments a 
inner join appointments p on p.appointment_id = a.parent_appointment_id 
where a.appointment_status = 'completed' and a.patient_id = 2
```

If there may be "missing" parent appointments, you might want to `left join` instead.

Note that this does not actually nest the results in the way that is showed in your sample data - but I don't think this would make a lot of sense here for that single additional column.